# How to call codebehind method from Jquery after autocomplete selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a autocomplete text box as and when the user types the city names are prompted. Once the user selects city name the selected value is retrieved using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#txtName').on('change', function() {
        $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
      }).change();
      $('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function(e, ui) {
        $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now I need to pass the selected value and call method in aspx.cs (code-behind) to retrieve further details of selected city.

How can I call a method from JQuery can somebody guide me towards that

Answer (score 0):

You must call ajax in autocompleteselect like this

```
$('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
     $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
     $.ajax({url: "aspx.cs",data:{value:ui.item.value}, success: function(result){
        //response from server
    }});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.Ajax` to send the selected value to the server (code-behind) and get the response:

```
$('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function(e, ui) {
  $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
  $.ajax({
    url: "your-page.aspx/GetCityDetails",
    data: { Name: this.value },
    success: function(result) {
      //Process the result from the code-behind.
    }
  });
});
```

Your code-behind must have a webmethod named `GetCityDetails` that accepts the `name` parameter and returns a `city` object as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `Web Method`

```
function GetDetails(cityId) {     
                 $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'Default.aspx/GetDetails',
                 data: {"cityId":cityId},
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (msg) {
                   console.log(msg);
                 },
                 error: function (e) {
                  console.log(e);

                 }
             });
         }

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#txtName').on('change', function() {
        $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
      }).change();
      $('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function(e, ui) {
        $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
        GetDetails(ui.item.value);
});
```

in your aspx page

```
[WebMethod]                                 //Default.aspx.cs
  public static void GetDetails(cityId)
  {
     //Your Logic
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Server Side changes

You need to mark that method with `WebMethod` attribute to call it from the client side or you need to create a web service.

```
[WebMethod]
public static yourObject GetCityDetails(string cityId)//name this method as per your needs.
{
  //Do whatever you want.
  return yourObject; //it can also be in JSON format.
}
```

#### Client Side changes

Make an ajax call to the method from the client side.

```
  $('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function(e, ui) {
  $('#selectedItem').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
  $.ajax({
    url: "yourpage.aspx/GetCityDetails", //same method name here.
    data: { cityId: this.value },
    success: function(result) {
      //do whatever you want with server side data here.
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my issue:

The following is the code in jquery part in .aspx

```
function SetCityName(cityName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetCityDetails',
            data: JSON.stringify({ cityName: cityName }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("CityName:" + cityName + "\n\nRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result.d);
            }
       });
    }
```

This is the code in .aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetCityDetails(string cityName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cityName);
            return "success";
        }
```

The trick part is using the following piece in JQuery. I have tried above alternatives provided but none worked apart from the below piece of code:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ cityName: cityName }),
```